# Auto layout 4 UILabels vertically with height according to their content/text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell`, and i am using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to automatically calculate the row height.

(I am replicating design of Facebook comments from iOS)

I need all the 4 label's height adjusted to height of their content.

> CC = Content compression CH = Content hugging [Horizontal/Vertical]
>
> Label 1: CC = 750/750
>            CH = 249/750
>
> Label 2: CC = 999/999
>            CH = 999/999
>
> Label 3: CC = 750/749
>            CH = 249/749
>
> Label 4: CC = 1000/1000
>            CH = 1000/1000

Here, Label 2 and Label 4 are the most important labels. I dont want them to shrink anyhow. Label 1 and Label 3 can shrink but to a limit.(let's say 30px)

My cell is as follows:
[image]

And i get this result:
[image]

Let me know if anyone need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your table view cell structure and it seems the issue is that `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of labels is not set.

You can either set it explicitly in Interface Builder or override table view cell's `updateViewConstraints` method:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    CGFloat gap = 40.0; // sum of leading and trailing space
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - gap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set layout constraint `width` and `Lines = 0` for both Label2 & Label4. See image below:
[image]

`Label1` set `top constraint` with `superview`, otherwise set `Vertical Spacing` with above label. Below is the result with large and short content for `Label3`.

[image]

[image]

Edit: Your custom cell like here:
[image]

And you should update layout depending element view container.

Comment: Label3 is good, but what if i get dynamic height in Label2 and Label4 both at the same time?

Comment: I just update my answer. But can't clear explain to you :(

Comment: Thanks, i will try and let you know.